# How to access static variable of java class in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Eg: I have a java class First

First.java

```
   `class First{
      public static TAG = "test"
    }`
```

Second.kt

```
  `class Second{
     First.TAG  /*Error classifier First does not have a companion object,and thus must be initialized here*/
   }`
```

So help me to call the static variable TAG declared in First.java inside Second.kt kotlin class

Comment: I am using both android and kotlin inside the same project

Comment: as a side note it should be `public static String TAG` you are missing String

Comment: use full qualified name instead of `First.TAG` use `<your package>.First.TAG` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Comment: Why would you do that? it's not clear what you are trying to do with First.TAG . If you want to create a member variable `var someMember = First.TAG` and why does TAG not have a type in your java class. I am guessing it's a String

Comment: Also in Kotlin you can use Companion object, just like static methods in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Java Class:

```
class First {
    public static String TAG = "test";
}
```

Kotlin Class:

```
class Second {
    val secondTag: String = First.TAG
}
```

and there is no problem.

Try with IntelliJ IDEA

```
fun main(args: Array < String > ) {
    val s = Second()
    println(s.secondTag)
}
```

prints `test`

Answer (score 1):

Just make a proper, static final constant.

```
class First {
      public static final String TAG = "test"
}
```

Now you can call it from Kotlin.

```
class Second {
   fun blah() {
       val tag = First.TAG
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Class

`package com.your.package
object First {
    val TAG: String= "Your TAG";
}`

Second Class

`class Second{
     First.TAG 
   }`

Kotlin doesn’t have static members or member functions,
you can use companion object